# How to use an existing marker for Google Maps API directionService instead of defining a new one?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Google Maps API to show directions to a location.

On page load, I set a marker on the map: (FYI: I haven't included the coordinates, but you can assume they are defined)

```
var destination = [xxx, yyy, 11, xxx, yyy]; //x-coord,y-coord,zoom,x-center,x-center
var dublin = [xxx, yyy, 11, xxx, yyy]; //x-coord,y-coord,zoom,x-center,x-center
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var directionsDublin;

function initialize() {

  directionsDublin = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  var centerMap = new google.maps.LatLng(destination[3],destination[4]);

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: centerMap,
    zoom: destination[2]
  });

  marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(destination[0], destination[1]),
      map: map
  });
  marker1.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.DROP);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

So the code above displays the map  with a marker on it.
I now have a button #tNorth.  Clicking it will show a route from a defined location.  Clicking again will remove the route and return to the original view.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $( "#tNorth" ).on( "click", function() {

    if ($("#north").css('display') != 'none') {
      //set zoom and center
      map.setZoom(destination[2]);
      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(destination[3], destination[4]));
      //remove the route
      directionsDublin.setMap(null);
      //remove the text
      $("#north").css('display':'none');
    }
    else {
      //create travel route
      var request2 = {
        origin: new google.maps.LatLng(dublin[0], dublin[1]),
        destination: new google.maps.LatLng(destination[0], destination[1]),
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
      };
      //display route on map
      directionsDublin.setMap(map);
      directionsService.route(request2, function(result, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDublin.setDirections(result);
        }
      });
      //add the text
      $("#north").css('display':'block');
    }
  });
});
```

This is my first use of the Maps API so I'm pretty happy!!

However, when the route is displayed, it places 2 new markers on the page.  Since the destination marker is already on the page, it gets overlayed by the new marker.
Is there a way for me to, instead of defining destination: new `google.maps.LatLng(destination[0], destination[1])`, that I could instead define something like `destination: marker1`??

It would be nicer than displaying two markers over each other...

Answer (score 2):

Use {suppressMarkers:true} in the [DirectionRendererOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions) to prevent the DirectionsRenderer from adding markers to the map (it will still show the route)

```
directionsDublin = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({suppressMarkers:true});
```